# Non-isomorphic Unicyclic Graphs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

How many different (non-isomorphic) connected graphs having N vertices, and exactly one cycle comprising K vertices exist?

Answer (score 1):

You can think of this family of graphs as a fusion between a cycle and a forest. The $K$ vertices of the singular cycle are connected to $N - K$ vertices in a forest (set of trees).

The trees of the forest are connected to the cycle at some root - so you need to know the number of rooted trees. Lastly, there can be at most $K$ attachment points, and the trees of the forest are in a cyclic order around the central unicycle.